# MySQL Count Including 0

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a total count of entries by month, over the course of several months.  Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT COUNT(siteCount) AS Hits, DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%b') AS Month 
FROM count 
WHERE redirectDomain LIKE 'http://domain.com' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%Y') = '2013'
AND DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%b') BETWEEN 'Sep' AND 'Nov'  
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%b')
```

This is working great except when the count is 0.  The month of Nov has 0 entries so it does not show in the results.  How can I get Nov included in the results and showing a count of 0?

I'm guessing I need either ISNULL or CASE, but I've tried both and cannot figure out how to make this work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: does between 'Sep' AND 'Nov' work? like month-wise it looks like string so i am unsure about that

Comment: I checked it doesn't work, you might want to change that to `in ('Sep','Oct','Nov')` instead

Comment: Both worked fine during testing.  I received a count of 612 for Oct and 1 for Sept.  Those are correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can't just `count` table only. below query might help you.

### UPDATED

```
SELECT month_tab.Mo, IF(x.Hists IS NULL, 0, x.Hists)
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Jan' AS Mo
    UNION
    SELECT 'Feb' AS Mo
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Jun' AS Mo
    UNION
    SELECT 'Aug' AS Mo
    UNION
    SELECT 'Sep' AS Mo
    UNION
    SELECT 'Oct' AS Mo
    UNION
    SELECT 'Nov' AS Mo
) month_tab
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT SUM(count.siteCount) AS Hists, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%b') Mo
FROM count
WHERE redirectDomain LIKE 'http://domain.com'
GROUP BY Mo
) x ON month_tab.Mo = x.Mo;
```

Comment: Tried this on [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7ebe/27/0) doesn't seem to work the way i expected it to.

Comment: @TinTran Thank you for sqlFiddle. I have updated. some month is skipped for short.

Answer (score 0):

Case is certainly an option...

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN 
              COUNT(`siteCount`) = 0 
     THEN 
          '0' 
     ELSE 
          COUNT(`siteCount`) 
          END AS Hits, 
          DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%b') AS Month
```

... but not necessary in this case (see full query with notes below):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(`siteCount`) AS Hits,

-- See below for an explanation about naming conventions... 'TIMESTAMP' is probably
-- a name you'd want to avoid as well. If you can't avoid it though, use `backticks`.
  DATE_FORMAT(`TIMESTAMP`,'%b') AS Month

-- I recommend changing the name of your database to something other than 'count'
-- because that can really confuse the system and make life much harder on you.
-- It's kind of like naming your daughter 'Daughter' or creating a PHP function
-- named 'function'. In either case you're eventually going to end up with a mess.
-- Fortunately, MySQL allows you to use `backticks` which, in this case, are
-- absolutely crucial (if for no other reason than maintaining sanity). ;)
FROM `count`

WHERE `redirectDomain` LIKE 'http://domain.com'

-- This will return a 4-digit numeric year (removing 'quotes')
AND DATE_FORMAT(`TIMESTAMP`,'%Y') = 2013

-- AND DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%b') BETWEEN 'Sep' AND 'Nov'
-- This doesn't know that you're talking about months... All it knows is to look
-- for values between the group of letters "Sep" and the group of letters "Nov".
-- For example, 'Feb' would not be counted as being between 'Jan' and 'Mar', because
-- it starts with the letter F, while 'Jul' and 'Jun' would.
-- Instead, convert to numbers:
AND DATE_FORMAT(`TIMESTAMP`,'%c') BETWEEN 9 AND 11  

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`TIMESTAMP`,'%b')

-- If you want the results ordered chronologically (instead of alphabetically) you
-- can use the same logic as is written above, converting letters to numbers.
-- However THIS time, use '%m' instead of '%c' because it will add a '0' to the
-- left of the month number. (Delete the next line if that's not what you want).
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`TIMESTAMP`,'%m') ASC
```

Comment: This had the same result.  Only values for Sep and Oct.  No result for  Nov.

Comment: @user3034801 please see updated answer... I apologize for overlooking as much as I did. Should work now though.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, it's not returning your `month` field because there aren't any rows (which is why your `count` is zero) - you could replace your `count` with a subselect which will keep them seperate from grouping etc:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT 
       COUNT(c2.siteCount) 
       FROM 
            count c2 
       WHERE 
            redirectDomain 
       LIKE 
           'http://domain.com' 
       AND c2.TIMESTAMP = c1.TIMESTAMP) as Hits,
           DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP, '%b') AS Month,
       FROM count c1

    -- ...
```

I have a feeling you shouldn't be using TIMESTAMP either... reserved words...?

Comment: Indeed, I had a same question about `TIMESTAMP`. It works well. try `create table ab (TIMESTAMP timestamp);` and `create table ab (timestamp timestamp);`. but not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem,just follow this-

I created a table..

```
        create table test(month text,site_count int null);

         insert into test values('Sept',1),('Oct',1);

         insert into test(month) values('Nov');
```

I did not give any value in the site_count column for the month 'Nov' i.e. the site_count of 'Nov' is null.Now I tried to count the site_count column according to the months and tried to get '0' for the month 'Nov' as in this month there was null in the site_count column.

I tried this following query and it worked,i.e. I got '0' in the site_count column for the month 'Nov' as you needed..

```
     select month,count(site_count) from test ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Hits) AS Hits,Month,MonthOrder
FROM
 (
 SELECT COUNT(siteCount) AS Hits, 
        DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%b') AS Month,
        DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%m') AS MonthOrder
 FROM count 
 WHERE redirectDomain LIKE 'http://domain.com' 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%Y') = '2013'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%b') IN ('Sep','Oct','Nov')
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%b')
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Jan' AS Month,'01' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Feb' AS Month,'02' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Mar' AS Month,'03' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Apr' AS Month,'04' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'May' AS Month,'05' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Jun' AS Month,'06' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Jul' AS Month,'07' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Aug' AS Month,'08' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Sep' AS Month,'09' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Oct' AS Month,'10' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Nov' AS Month,'11' AS MonthOrder
 UNION SELECT 0 AS Hits, 'Dec' AS Month,'12' AS MonthOrder
 )T1
GROUP BY Month,MonthOrder
ORDER BY MonthOrder ASC
```

delete your checking conditions as you see fit, i don't think you need the `IN ('Sep','Oct','Nov')` anymore it's up to you.
Here's the [sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7ebe/24/0)